# Moving an image inside in another frame image android

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-image

I have a frame image and another image selected from gallery. What i want is to place that image inside the boundary of that frame image and also I can apply onTouchListener on the image selected from gallery.
Like in the app whose link is provided following.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyrebirdstudio.pipcamera

Any idea or concept will be helpful.
**My IDEA**
Here is what i am thinking to create a relative layout and setting the Picture Frame as a background and then scaling the other image according to the size of the relative layout. Then i can apply onTouchlistener on the image easily.
Am i going in right direction or there is some better way though which i can achieve the desire results?
Thanks in advance.